# How do you create a Composite file in C++

Tags: c++, file-handling, file-systems, files

I am looking to create a "Composite file" in C++, basically a composite file is a file containing files, (examples: .docx, .jar, etc) these files can usually be renamed as .zip and opened with a .zip opening program, but the program using them don't usually unzip them prior to use, nor do they compress them after use, they are just file systems that look like single files.  How do I do this from C++?

Comment: You take an existing archive manager library or write your own. What's the question exactly?

Comment: You REALLY don't want to reinvent this particular wheel.  Use tar or gzip or something similar.  Wrap a batch file (shell script) around it if you want to conceal the details.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm: `gzip` is a compressor, not an archiver. `tar`, `cpio`, and  (preferably) `pax` are the typical Unix archivers.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: You're right, of course.  The key point is "Don't reinvent the wheel."

Answer (score 4):

There are many composite file formats:  [tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html), [zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)), [7z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535036/headers-structure-of-7z-files) to name a few. There are basically two ways to create any of them in c++.  Either download and import some library that will do the work for you or read the  specifications so you know how the format should look right down to the bit level and then write some code that creates a binary file that conforms to those specifications.